# Mapbox Android: How to check if a region is already downloaded?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapbox

I am struggling on how to prevent Mapbox Android to download region (for offline use) if the region was already cached.

I Don't really know of the `offlineManager.listOfflineRegions` works. Do I have to manually check if the region I want to download is already existing in this list ?
MapBox seems to not checks if the map is already downloaded but download it again.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maps SDK is not going to download any additional tiles if required are already in place, it will verify those tiles in the first place though. If you'd like to manually check if the region has already been downloaded, you can use the metadata: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/offline/#metadata

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will dig into this.

Reading you saying that the SDK will check the file, make me wondering if it is possible to get something that tells you that the SDK is verifying and not downloading.